# how to remove a certain set of characters from the end of a string

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a column DBNAME where the values can be as follows:

```
ORCLDBhostone1
ORCLDBhosttwo2
ORCLDBhostthree3
ORCLDBhostfour4
ORCLDBhost
```

Here 1,2,3,4 are the instance numbers,in RAC databases.And if there is no number at the end then it is a standalone database,and doesnt need any truncation.

How can i remove the last character,but only if it is in between 1-6.
Please suggest.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(col, '[1-6]$', '')
```